# Express, keep variables for each user

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using socket.io on top of Express/Node

Right now I'm using this method:

```
// get room name from URL
var requestRoom;
app.get('/editor/:room', function(req, res) {
  requestRoom = req.params.room;
  res.render('editor/editor', {
    title: 'Editor'
  });
});

// use that room name for private rooms within socket.io
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.join(requestRoom);
  // rest of socket.io code....
```

to grab the `room-name` from a URL that looks like `sitename.io/editor/[room-name]`.

Then I'm using `requestRoom` as a variable for `socket.to(requestRoom).broadcast..` for sending the socket packets to a specific room.

---

**The problem**

Each time a new user visits the app, `requestRoom` gets *repopulated for all users*, instead of just for the user that just joined.

Is there a way to start a new 'instance' with own variables for each 'session'? 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can't exactly help you with your problem, but here's a useful reminder for Node beginners : Node is single processed, so your server code will only be executed in one instance, and all users will technically be served by that instance. In stead of creating variables or classes for each new user, trying storing that kind of information in JSON objects, like `var Users = { 'room1': [23, 57, 122], 'room2': [5, 28] }`. Sorry for not answering your question but I know this is something I had trouble conceiving at the beginning and understanding this eventually helped out a lot.

Comment: im scoping the variable within each socket connection instead and it works just fine - the single instance part was what was confusing me so thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create new instance for each session.

But, you can solve this issue by sending the room name from the client.
When you connect to WebSocket using socket.io-client, add the room name to query parameter.

Client:

```
var requestRoom = "roomName";
io('/', {query: "requestRoom=" + requestRoom})
```

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var requestRoom = socket.request._query.requestRoom;
    socket.join(requestRoom);
    // rest of socket.io code....
```

EDIT:

Nicholas Kyriakides used simpler way to solve this.

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var refererSplit = socket.request.headers.referer.split('/');
    var requestRoom = refAr[refererSplit.length-1]; //Considering Room name is at the end of the path.
    socket.join(requestRoom);
    // rest of socket.io code....
```

No need to pass roomName from the client.

Comment: actually no, I can still use the name from the server and just scope each variable within the socket connection - but thanks anyway

Comment: Do you mean you put the ```io.on('connection', function(socket) {``` inside the router itself??

Comment: No, I've put the URL sniffing in `io.on('connection' .... ` I'm getting the URL using `socket.request.headers.referer` there and then parse it using `url.parse` , then split it on `/` and take the 3rd part of it which is the room name.